# how do I increase the variance of an array?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have an array as below:

```
W = np.random.rand(256, 4, 4,1).astype(np.float32)
```

I want to increase the variance of `W`. For this I do the following:

```
mw=np.mean(W)
alpha=1
W=(W-mw)*alpha+mw
```

But when I see `W`'s mean before and after doing this, it is the same, and the content of `W` has not changed! 
Could you please tell me what the problem is? Did I understand `mw` and the minus action incorrectly?
Thank you.

Comment: You are subtracting a constant, multiplying by one, then adding the same constant. What did you expect?

Comment: Your `alpha` is `1`. Change `alpha` to a number like `100` and observe the larger variance in numbers in `W`.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to change the alpha above. when I change the alpha to 0.2 or 0.8 the mean value is the same and just some W values is changed. is it true?

Comment: How can I understand the variance of values in W has increased?